# How to replace the first instance of a string in a pd datafframe?

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have looked through the df.replace() and have not been able to successfully fix my problem.

Say I have a df and I want to change only the first instance of the word cat to Brown Cat how can I achieve this?

Everything I have tried will change both Cat's to Brown Cat.

```
Original DF           Desired Output
 Animals              Animals
0  Cat              0 Brown Cat
1  Dog              1 Dog
2 Snail             2 Snail
3 Fish              3 Fish
4 Cat               4 Cat
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the index of first cat and replace it

```
first_cat = df.Animals.eq('Cat').idxmax()
df.loc[first_cat,'Animals'] = 'Brown Cat'
```

Comment: `df.loc[first_cat, "Animals"] = 'Brown Cat'` should be preferred to set the value of a specific cell.

Comment: you kept `iloc` instead of `loc`, I think the above will error out.

Comment: sorry, fixed it

Comment: One thing to note here is that, in the event there is no 'Cat' in the data, the value at index 0 will be replaced by Brown Cat

Comment: How would you over come that?

Comment: First check if element is present `df.Animals.str.contains('Cat')`, if True, apply the above code

Comment: Cheers for that mate

Comment: If you were to make the column names dynamic how would you rewrite this : first_cat = df.Animals.eq('Cat').idxmax()  so that it chooses the first column as in something like df[col_titles[0]]